# Formatting a data bound control according to bound data

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datarepeater

I am displaing some data in a repeater using the following -

```
        BindingSource bindingSource5 = new BindingSource();
        bindingSource5.DataSource = BookingManager.GetBookingDaysForDayWithBookingFields(DateTime.Now.AddDays(+4));

        lbSchoolFri.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource5, "SchoolName");
        lbTeacherFri.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource5, "FullName");

        lbDurationFri.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource5, "BookingDayDuration");
        lbYear.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource5, "Year");

        cbSchoolFri.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bindingSource5, "SchoolContacted");
        cbTeacherFri.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bindingSource5, "TeacherContacted");
        cbEmailFri.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bindingSource5, "LetterSent");

        dataRepeater5.DataSource = bindingSource5;
```

If cbSchoolFriday is checked, I want to change the back colour of the Picture Box pbFriday to red. How can I do this?

Screenshot - 
[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can use `Format` event handler but what about `CheckedChanged`?

Comment: Could you provide an example for the format? I have been trying this with no success. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this. It appears the dataRepeater has a DrawItem event. Within here, I put the following code -

```
private void dataRepeater1_DrawItem(object sender, Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DataRepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cbSchoolMon = e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls["cbSchoolMon"] as CheckBox;
        Label lbTeacherIDMon = e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls["lbTeacherIDMon"] as Label;

        PictureBox pbMon = e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls["pbMon"] as PictureBox;

        if (cbSchool.Checked)
        {
            pbMon.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            pbMon.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play with `DataBindings` without using `CheckedChanged` event, here is the solution:

```
Binding bind = new Binding("Checked", bindingSource5, "SchoolContacted");
bind.Format += (s,e) => {
    e.Value = (int)e.Value == 1;
    dataRepeater.ItemTemplate.BackColor = ((bool)e.Value) ? Color.Red : Color.White;
};
cbSchoolFri.DataBindings.Add(bind);
```

I'm not sure if your `dataRepeater.ItemTemplate` has a `DataBindings` property so that we can use `dataRepeater.ItemTemplate.DataBindings`?

Comment: Yes, the dataRepeater.ItemTemplate has a DataBindings property. The above seems to be almost there, however the top row is always the default form colour and a few are red even when the checkox is not checked? Cheers

Comment: @MattBaughan I'm not sure what your `dataRepeater.ItemTemplate` is? Is it some kind of class which applies some style on a set of rows or any other controls?

Comment: The datarepeater.ItemTemplate - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.itemtemplate.aspx All I have done is data bound the repeater to a DataTable. Have I mis-understood your question? Cheers

Comment: @MattBaughan I've tried playing a little with `DataRepeater` and I can see that `ItemTemplate` applies on all its rows, I think you should provide some screen shot of your form to help me see what it looks like. If you change `ItemTemplate.BackColor`, that of course applies not only on 1 particular row.

Comment: I have edited my question with a screenshot. I have since changed my method to set the background colour of a picture box (pbFri), rather than the background of the entire Item. Thanks